# Rasberry PI : Unable to set my RPI as a router

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, router

I have a RPI which has a wired connection to our organization router and a WIFI dongle plugged in its USB port.

Firstly I followed this instruction set:

**http://sirlagz.net/2012/08/09/how-to-use-the-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-pointrouter-part-1/**

Below are my configuration:

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    wireless-essid Test
    wireless-key ABCDEFGHIJ
    wireless-channel 11
    wireless-mode managed
    address 192.xxx.x.2
    network 192.xxx.1.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    route add default gw 198.xxx.1.1
```

Below are the syslogs:

```
Dec 13 09:46:07 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Dec 13 09:46:07 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
Dec 13 09:46:07 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b RADIUS: starting accounting session 52AAD693-00000003
Dec 13 09:46:07 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[2114]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) b8:b4:xx:xx:xx:xx
Dec 13 09:46:07 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[2114]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.xx.1.57
```

Below is my hostapd config:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ssid=TEST
wpa_passphrase=TESTTESTTEST
hw_mode=g
channel=11
wmm_enabled=0
```

Below is the DHCP config:

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

send host-name = rasberrypi;
subnet 192.xxx.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.xxx.1.3 192.xxx.1.240;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option routers 192.xxx.1.2;
    option domain-name "test.in";
    default-lease-time 21600;
    max-lease-time 43200;
};
```

The issue is that on my WIFI mobile after selecting and entering password for my WIFI essid I keep getting "**Obtaining IP address ..**" and does not gets connected at all. I tried with other devices but same output.

Are my configuration and setup fine?

```
# iwconfig
mon.wlan0  IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I have dnsmasq also setup and below is what I have as in its configuration:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf  | grep -v '#'
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.xxx.1.2,192.xxx.1.254,255.255.255.0,12h
```

I do see the following lines in my syslog:

```
Dec 13 09:46:07 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[2114]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b
Dec 13 09:46:07 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[2114]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.xxx.1.57 b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b
Dec 13 09:46:11 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[2114]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b
Dec 13 09:46:11 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[2114]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.xxx.1.57 b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b
Dec 13 09:46:19 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[2114]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b
Dec 13 09:46:19 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[2114]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.xxx.1.57 b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b
Dec 13 09:46:35 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[2114]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b
Dec 13 09:46:35 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[2114]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.xxx.1.57 b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b
```

Comment: What chipset does your dongle have?

Comment: lsusb ==> Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter

Comment: This might sound stupid, but I've heard somewhere that wpa keys have a minimum length, you could try using a 8character password.

Comment: Yes it is more than 6 characters, I have updated in the question as well

Comment: can you try using dnsmasq?

Comment: I have updated the question with requested details. It seems that dnsmasq is installed

Comment: Configure your pi with no security and take a sniff with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or something else. This is the best way to find who fails (AP or STA).

Comment: Please let me know how to setup my RPI with no security

Comment: Just set `auth_algs=1` and `wpa=0` in hostapd.conf

Comment: I have set the above option - trying to capture via wireshark

Comment: Sorry since this is an embedded system box - I cannot install any tool due to space issue

Comment: You can sniff from an external PC. You will have your AP (which is your Pi), your STA (the client) and a sniffer.

Comment: The wifi dongle is directly connected to the raspberry pi or thought a HUB? It could be that it is not receiving enough power to work properly...

Comment: It is directly connected to RPI

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this ?

```
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
# I've set these to WPA-PSK to indicate that we are using a Pre-Shared Key with CCMP encryption.
# Otherwise, hostapd also has a built in RADIUS server that we can use for authentcation
# But I'll leave that to another post.
```

Add at least: `wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK` in your hostapd config, else by default it will use RADIUS. As we can see in your logs.

Comment: Thanks I have added the same in my /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf file, however the issue persists. I get this logs now:

Dec 13 10:48:22 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b RADIUS: starting accounting session 52AAE56D-00000000
Dec 13 10:48:22 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
Dec 13 10:48:22 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[2116]: DHCPREQUEST(wlan0) 10.0.0.10 b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b 
Dec 13 10:48:22 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[2116]: DHCPNAK(wlan0) 10.0.0.10 b8:b4:2e:76:ad:1b wrong address